# With KarateUI, is it possible to click inside an element by relative coordonates

Tags: karate

In one cas, Karate doesn't recognize well a webelement.
My UIElement has, in the browser, a size (640 x 34), but Karate, thru the position keyword, indicates a size (642 x 375) with a wrong height

the issue is when I want to click on it, nothing occurs because of the different of height.

Is there a way to do a click inside an element using its relative coordonates.

in selenium, I'm able to do a clickAt(300,10) for example

I tried some code such as

```
("#myItem").click(300,10)

def pos=position("#myItem")
print(pos)
mouse.move(pos.x+pos.width/2, pos.y+10).click()
```

but nothing works.

any clue will be helpful...
thanks and regards

Comment: `mouse()` is supposed to work, please do try to contribute code fixes to karate, it is open-source. at the very least replicating the issue on a public web-site